# Custom ASP.NET Core Logger using Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

In my project I use Serilog and ASP.Net Core. The initialization part looks like that:

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var logFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
logFactory.AddSerilog().AddConsole();
return provider;
```

This will add Serilog to the logging pipeline.

I want to add to the logger an ability to say whether there was logs with type 'Warning' or not in order to make some result message. For example it could be a method that returns simple bool saying about that.

How should I do it in a correct way? Can I somehow override current Core behavior by changing the way the logger handles 'Warning' logs in order to save somewhere the fact that LogWarning method has been called? Or should I implement my own logger (ILogger) as well as ILoggerFactory and ILoggerProvider with needed functionality? But then how can I save Serilog part in that scenario?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place. You're essentially wanting to log your logs, which is redundant. You can access your log store at any time and filter by severity. If you want some sort of monitor, just set up a background task to monitor the store and send an alert or whatever when anything with warning+ severity is added to the store.

Comment: I think it is easier to get information right from the logger itself than perform reading and filtering through all my logs (stored in files). And it will be definitely faster. It should be a matter of several lines of code for such idea, creating a background task seems like an overhead.